# Latex and Vim usage

Tags: vim, plugins, latex, tex

How can I use Latex effectively in VIM?

Is there a way to configure compile errors by highlighting the line in vim?

I have syntax highlight. What are other recommended add-ons? Is a makefile the recommended way to compile a latex file to pdf?

TexWorks lets you open and replace the opened pdf everytime it's recompiled. Is there a plugin to do something similar in vim?

Answer (score 34):

I've just begun playing around with [LaTeX-Box](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3109). It seems like a good plugin. I, also used VIM-LaTeX for a while, but I didn't really like the key mappings, and it seemed a bit to heavyweight as Jeet described.

I like LaTeX-Box so far because it used [latexmk](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) to compile, which is what I was using anyway. Latexmk will sit in the background and watch your .tex file for changes, and then automatically compile for you. And if you use a pdf viewer which refreshed changes (such as evince on Linux) you can see updates every time you change. Adding

```
let g:LatexBox_latexmk_options = "-pvc -pdfps"
```

to my .vimrc got latexmk working properly. You also need the latexmk script somewhere on you PATH. The key mapping to start latexmk is the same as Vim-Latex's compile: '\ll' (that's lowercase LL).

I also use SuperTab plugin for completions, which is great. And I took the dictionary files from Vim-LaTeX so I have a ton of auto completion words to use. This dictionary file is: ftplugin/latex-suite/dictionaries/dictionary in the vim-latex files. What I did was copy this file into ~/.vim/dictionaries/ and renamed it 'tex' then I added these lines to my .vimrc file:

```
set filetype on
au FileType * exec("setlocal dictionary+=".$HOME."/.vim/dictionaries/".expand('<amatch>'))
set complete+=k
```

Then if I type the beginning of a latex command and hit 'tab' I will get a list of completions. Pretty handy. BTW that 'au' command in the vimrc will also load dictionaries for any other filetypes if you want. A useful trick.

Comment: FYI, you can specify the compiler that VIM-LaTeX uses by setting `g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf`; i.e., to use `latexmk`, just  put the line `let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'latexmk -pdf'` in your `.vimrc`.

Comment: The last versions of LatexBox need `let g:LatexBox_latexmk_preview_continuously=1` and `let g:LatexBox_latexmk_async=1` to update every change.

Answer (score 15):

check out [vim latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/)

If you use vim latex put the following in your .vimrc:

```
let g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat='pdf'
```

and it should compile to pdf by default. (I think the default compilation key
is \ll).

Comment: what exactly is the "\ll" key?

Comment: I mean, you hit \ll (three keys) to compile the document.

Comment: The `\ ` only works if you have not rebound your `<leader>` key. It's `<leader>ll`, to be exact. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can also check [AutomaticLatexPlugin](http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net), it has many nice features (see the [features list](http://atp-vim.sourceforge.net/features.shtml)). 
Its main point is to compile the document in the background using autocommands, so that you are free from compilation cycle. This works nicely on Linux and MacOs. It contains (extended version of) Latex-Box.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

[vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) is great. But I found it too heavyweight for my tastes. I prefer more of a "Vim with LaTeX compile & view" approach, rather than "A LaTeX IDE with Vim key-bindings". So I rolled my own: '[TeX-PDF: Lightweight "stay-out-of-your-way" TeX-to-PDF development support](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3230)'.

Also check out: "[LaTeX Help : Help for LaTeX in vim.help format](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=206)" for calling up help of LaTeX from within Vim.

Comment: I tried you plugin, it is simplistic but gets the job done (compiling and viewing).

Comment: Quick note, the extension of the file should be .bz2 not .gz. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. New version has compression matching the extension.

Answer (score 6):

I personally can get by on:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tex set makeprg=pdflatex\ %\ &&\ open\ %:r.pdf
```

where `open` is Mac OS X specific. Linux users will want a different command to view their compiled file after running `make`. This works best if you have mapped a key to write and then run `make` (and you should - once you have single key save and compile, you'll never go back).

Comment: On Linux you can use the command `xdg-open` in place of `open`. It opens the default PDF reader.